# add and obtain data of ngRepeat of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Well I have a problem, I have a ng-repeat that shows me the users currently, every day I have to add the user's meals, this is why I have 5 checkboxes, 3 have to be marked and 2 not, the problem when ready users add these Data of the meals, but I do not receive any data from the checkbox.

Promptly, I need to add to the data that I receive in my function the value of those checkboxes.

```
<tr ng-repeat="users in usersData">
    <td>
        {{ $index + 1 }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ users.id }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ users.apellidos }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ users.nombres }}
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" style="width: 100px;" ng-model="users.desayuno" ng-checked="true">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" style="width: 100px;" ng-model="users.almuerzo" ng-checked="true">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="checkbox"  style="width: 100px;" ng-model="users.te" ng-checked="true">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" style="width: 100px;" ng-model="users.cena">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" style="width: 100px;" ng-model="users.amanecida">
    </td>
</tr>
```

and here dont show nothing of `users.desayuno` `users.almuerzo` `users.te` `users.cena` `users.amanecida`

```
$scope.saveDataDining = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.usersData, function(obj) {
      console.log(obj);
    });
  };
```

here have a plunker with the problem.

https://plnkr.co/edit/tHNhKQObkjRtUEfmI19o?p=preview

Comment: Never used `ng-checked` & `ng-model` directive  together, [reference here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/attrs.js#L199).. Just by making check-box value true using `ng-checked` doesn't update `ng-model` value. Rather you should explicitly set those needful flag to true by looping over each element..

Comment: Good try different ways I ended up using ´ng-checked´, but even so I do not get the values of the checkboxes, also without using ´ng-checked´

Comment: before binding a data, you can set each elements flag to true easily like `angular.forEach($scope.usersData, function(obj) {
      angular.extend(obj, {desayuno: true,almuerzo: true, te: true });
    });`

Comment: well this work  thanks.

Comment: The [documentation for ng-checked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) clearly states: **Note that this directive (ng-checked) should not be used together with [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel), as this can lead to unexpected behavior.**

Answer (score 0):

As @georgeawg states:

> The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) for ng-checked clearly states: Note that this directive (ng-checked) should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.

1. Initialize the objects in the controller instead

   ```
   $scope.usersData = [{
     id: 1,
     nombres: "Amilkar Shegrid",
     apellidos: "Contreras Castro",
     sexo: "MASCULINO",
     codido_seguro: 5213635,
     desayuno: true,
     almuerzo: true,
     te: true,
     cena: false,
     amanecida: false
   }, {...
   ```
2. and add a `ng-change` or `ng-click` function to the checkboxes to set the values

   ```
   // controller
   $scope.toggleDesayuno = function(userid) {
     var u = $scope.usersData.find((user)=>userid==user.id)
     u.desayuno = !u.desayuno
   }

   // template
   <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" style="width: 100px;" ng-click="toggleDesayuno(users.id)">
   ```